# NativeScript gesture state name to corresponding number

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to use gestures in my nativescript-angular app. When I log this:

```
console.log("Pinch scale: " + args.scale + " state: " + args.state);
```

`args.state` gives me numbers (1,2,3), but [in the docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/enums/_ui_gestures_.gesturestatetypes) they referred to names such as: *began* or *cancelled*. Waht is the corresponding name to each number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GestureStateTypes are defined like this

```
export enum GestureStateTypes {
    /**
     * Gesture canceled.
     */
    cancelled,
    /**
     * Gesture began.
     */
    began,
    /**
     * Gesture changed.
     */
    changed,
    /**
     * Gesture ended.
     */
    ended
}
```

As per `enum` nature in `TS` first elemnet will auto assigned 0 if it is not assigned any value and then it will be auto incremented .

so final result will be `cancelled=0`,`began=1`,`changed=2` and `ended=3`. but you should avoid directly checking to its value like `args.state==1` and instead should use `args.state==GestureStateTypes.began`.